# Eclipse Arduino make: *** error 1

Tags: eclipse, gcc, makefile, arduino, avr-gcc

Below is the error that I get when I try to build my project. I am unsure what file or directory it is talking about. All the files and directories are within the project directory.

I followed the instructions in http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse to set up my IDE.

Should the Arduino core files be within the project directory and specifically added to the Arduino core library? All I gave it was the `liArduinoCore.a` file that was produced by my Arduino IDE. Could this be the issue?

#### The error message

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project CustomLEDPoi ****

make all 
Building target: CustomLEDPoi.elf
Invoking: AVR C++ Linker
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,CustomLEDPoi.map,--cref Wl,--gc-sections -    L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\src" -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src" -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\CustomLEDPoi\arduinolib" -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\CustomLEDPoi\lib" -mmcu=atmega328p -o "CustomLEDPoi.elf"  ./src/glowstick2.o  ./lib/CShiftPWM.o ./lib/MeetAndroid.o ./lib/hsv2rgb.o  ./arduinolib/HardwareSerial.o ./arduinolib/SPI.o   -lArduinoCore
avr-gcc.exe: Wl,--gc-sections: No such file or directory
make: *** [CustomLEDPoi.elf] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a `-` is missing for `Wl,--gc-sections`. It should actually be `-Wl,--gc-sections`. Without the proper flag, the compiler assumes that it's a source file. You should check the makefile and verify.